# monolog multiple formatter php

Tags: php, logging, monolog

I am using monolog and trying ti use 2 formatter.
 1. for a file using regular formatter 
 2. using gelf handler with logstash formatter

code:

```
$logger = new Monolog\Logger("my-app");
$strHandle = new Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler($settings['path'],$settings['max_files'], $settings['level']);
$formatter = new LogstashFormatter("name");
$strHandle->setFormatter($formatter);
$logger->pushProcessor(new Monolog\Processor\UidProcessor());
$handler = new \Monolog\Handler\GelfHandler(new \Gelf\Publisher(new \Gelf\Transport\TcpTransport("localhost", "1221")));
$logger->pushHandler($handler);
$logger->pushHandler($strHandle);
$logger->info("test");
```

that is working but the format of logstash is also in the file 
I want something like :

$gelfHandler->setFormatter($formatter);

I tried this but got 500 error

```
   $logger = new Monolog\Logger("my-app");
    $strHandle = new Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler($settings['path'],$settings['max_files'], $settings['level']);
    $logger->pushProcessor(new Monolog\Processor\UidProcessor());
    $handler = new \Monolog\Handler\GelfHandler(new \Gelf\Publisher(new \Gelf\Transport\TcpTransport("localhost", "1221")));
    $formatter = new LogstashFormatter("name");
$handler->setFormatter($formatter);
    $logger->pushHandler($handler);
    $logger->pushHandler($strHandle);
    $logger->info("test");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use only `GelfMessageFormatter` with `GelfHandler`. https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/doc/02-handlers-formatters-processors.md#formatters

Do you have an exact error? Did you try without `LogstashFormatter`for Gelf?

Comment: thanks , but I need the logstash format  , and want to write the regular  format for files

Comment: got Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Gelf\Publisher::publish() must be an instance of Gelf\MessageInterface, string given, call

Comment: Yes, and GelfMessageFormatter creates an Message object of MessageInterface https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Formatter/GelfMessageFormatter.php#L88
So you need to use GelfMessageFormatter. Maybe Logstash will understand this format and convert it internally? Do not have experience in logstash :) But google finds a plugin https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-gelf.html